# Difference between where clause in subquery or join condition

Tags: sql, performance, join, subquery

I ran into interesting question when I compare the query I construct myself and the query constructed by entity framework, here is the query I made in stored procedure:

```
select *
from TableA a
    join (select b.Col2, c.Col3
         from TableB b
            join TableC c on b.Col1=c.Col1
        where b.Col2 in (1,2,3,4)
        ) as bc on a.Col3=bc.Col3
```

and here is the query constructed by entity framework:

```
select *
from TableA a
    join (select b.Col2, c.Col3
         from TableB b
            join TableC c on b.Col1=c.Col1
    ) as bc on a.Col3=bc.Col3 and bc.Col2 in (1,2,3,4)
```

my question is where sql compiler is smart enough to optimize the query in the same way? (assume the index is properly defined on the joining/where condition.

Comment: Depends on the compiler/optimizer. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: have you run a query plan on both to see if there is a difference?

Comment: You could also run each one a few times to see if there is a performance difference.  If tableb.col2 was indexed, my guess is that filtering in the subquery would be much faster.  Otherwise, I'm not sure.

Comment: Most SQL compilers will recognize that the filter conditions should go as close to the inputs as possible.  Most, but not all.  I'm pretty sure MS Access won't, and I don't think MySQL will.

Comment: It is unlikely to be optimized, but the simple way to find out us to check the query plan in the EXPLAIN output

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the version of sql server I am using. It is SQL 2005.

Comment: and I have check the execution plan that they are the same. But I am not so persuaded because my TableC is really small (less than 10 records), I am not sure whether the execution plan will be the same if the table is much larger (if SQL optimize in a different way)

Answer (score 0):

In some of the smart optimizers like Teradata, any of the two queries will be rewritten same way:

```
 select a.columns,b.Col2,c.Col3  
 from TableA a

join TableB b
join TableC c 
on b.Col1=c.Col1
on a.Col3=bc.Col3 and bc.Col2 in (1,2,3,4)
```

See the explain to see what your DBMS is doing.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the version of sql server I am using. It is SQL 2005.

Comment: HLGEM, this is what I hope too, I just want to make sure SQL 2005 is doing the same thing or something different.